# storing custom historical audio metadata in a RoR database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

My RoR 3.2 site is an archive of historical mp3 recordings that must be inputted/uploaded via a form (by me) and thereafter can be searched and downloaded. I need to store metadata* about the mp3's that can look like this, among about 35 other similarly esoteric form entries:

> In WesternHistoricalCatalogue, this mp3 can be found on pages 2,3 and 6, and in NorthernHistoricalCatalogue on pages 1 and 5.

This seems to require some quite complex RoR models. For example, it seems that I need to create a `Page` model with a HABTM association to a `Catalogue` model which has a HABTM association to my `MP3` model.

The result is all sorts of models for things like 'pages' or 'years' just to handle multiple entries. And my form is going to be complex to create as well.

Is there a better way?

--
*using the term 'metadata' as a document librarian might (or iTunes does), not in the sense used by database developers on SO as information about transactions and processes.

Comment: As I understand it, using MongoDB instead of Postgresql would let me enter multiple values for a given attribute, but this seems like a long walk to take just to model my MP3 files with multiple `Page` and `Catalogue` entries (plus, I'd lose ad hoc queries). Does my wanting to associate my MP3 files with multiple `Page` numbers within a couple of different `Catalogues` require these separate `Page` models and the like? Any tips are appreciated!